# 23-month-old no longer napping in her crib

Tags: toddler, naps

My kid is 23 months old and turns 2 in 2 weeks. She is able to sleep at night on her own since we used the cry-it-out method late last year. She usually has one 1.5-2 hour nap after lunch. However, she has been refusing to nap in her crib for the last 2 days. She can't go to sleep on her own for her naps so I have to hold her for about 10 minutes before putting her in her crib. It used to work but the past 2 days, she'll sleep in my arms but will wake up the minute I put her down.

Anyone else faced this or know how I can help her to nap in her crib again?

We recently came back from a 4 day overseas trip. On that trip she napped, but the timings were not the same. However, the 2 days after we came back, she was able to nap fine. So I'm not sure if the issue is caused by the trip or a 2 year old sleep regression. I'm under the impression that a sleep regression is refusal to sleep. However, she's not refusing to sleep. Just wakes up when I put her down.

**Update**: She stayed asleep for her nap when I put her in her crib on Sun and Mon. Thought I was out of the woods, unfortunately I was wrong. Last 2 days I couldn't put her down so I tried cry it out. First day she cried for 50 minutes napped for 40 minutes. Woke up crying. Second day cried for 50 minutes and napped for 50 minutes. Woke up crying. Anyone know if the duration will get longer and she will not wake up crying? She didn't wake up crying when I used to put her down. And her naps used to be longer.

Comment: My kids go through that as they are phasing-out of mid-day naps. Some weeks they won't sleep at all (and turn into nightmares by dinner time), and then they go back to napping 2-3 hours during the day. My daycare provider said that it is a normal thing for them to go through phases like that and I wouldn't be too worried unless it is making them physically ill.

Comment: Thanks. She's tired though so I'm not sure about phasing out the naps. She can sleep in my arms but she wakes up the minute I put her in her crib. So far it's been 2 days bad, 2 days good and 2 days bad. I did cry it out with her again. She cried for 50 minutes. Nap for 50 minutes then woke up crying.

Answer (score 1):

just a thought... If she's tired and crying when you place her down for a nap, can you try changing the time of her nap? A little earlier perhaps? Here's my thought process: little ones often reach the point of being inconsolable when they are "over tired" or "over stimulated". If you put her down for the nap a 10-20 minutes earlier, it might be easier for her to sleep. -el